# Django Forms - Fields containing arrays

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have a couple fields within a form that I'd like to be an array of values. How can I achieve something like

```
categories['sale']['price']
categories['sale']['currency']
categories['sale']['frequency']
```

and

```
image[0]
image[1]
image[2]
```

These fields containing array would be part of a form containing regular fields. If possible, how does one deal with validation?

Bonus question: If I had dynamic fields by themselves, I'd use a Formset?

Comment: Formsets are for creating multiple form instances. If you need to relate data in a formset to a parent model, you'd use an inline formset. If you need to store multiple values in a field, my recommendation would be to break those out into a separate model and relate them via ManyToMany

Comment: @Brandon - I've been reading the docs but I'm having a hard time -- I'd like to have a form that deals with a couple models (main model that branches out, includes one-to-one a one-to-many) What would I do with a inline FormSet after I created it? (as shown in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) Would I use it a form? Would I insert it in another form?

Comment: Inline formsets are really nice in that they will automatically relate the model instances created by the formset to a parent model, given the model in the formset has a foreign key back to the parent. I use an M2M when I simply need to select a pre-existing set of object to relate to a parent model. When I need to create or edit multiple objects at a time, I use a formset. A formset is a standalone class, it's not part of another form class, but you can specify that the formset use a particular form class, which is where validation can go, etc.